# how to apply in python mobile averaging considering periodic boundary conditions in data

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I would like to perform mobile averaging considering periodic boundary conditions. I try to make myself clear.

I have this data:

```
Date,Q
1989-01-01 00:00,0
1989-01-02 00:00,1
1989-01-03 00:00,4
1989-01-04 00:00,6
1989-01-05 00:00,8
1989-01-06 00:00,10
1989-01-07 00:00,11
```

I would like to compute the mobile averaging considering 3 data: the next and the previous.
In particular, I would like to use same option in the "rolling" function where the first data (0 in python framework) were able to take into account the last one and vice versa the last one the first one. This would allows me to have a sort of periodic boundary conditions.

Indeed, I have applied the following:
First, I read the dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, index_col = 0,  parse_dates=True)
```

then I apply the "rolling" as

```
df['Q'] = pd.Series(df["Q"].rolling(3, center=True).mean())
```

However, I get the following results:

```
Date
1989-01-01     NaN
1989-01-02    1.66
1989-01-03    3.66
1989-01-04    6
1989-01-05    8
1989-01-06    9.66
1989-01-07     NaN
```

I know that I could apply the "min_periods=1" option but this is not what I want. Indeed, It is clear that in the second row the result is correct:

```
1.66 = (0+1+4)/3
```

However, I would like to have this result in the first row:

```
(0+1+11)/3
```

As you can noticed, the number 11 is the value of the last row. Similarly, I expect in the last row:

```
(10+11+0)/3
```

where 0 is the value of the first row.

Do you have some suggestions or idea?

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: could you show the expected output? or what is the logic ?

Comment: I have tried to improve the questions in order to explain also the expected results.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just duplicate the values before the first one and after last one, sort the dataframe, and do the rolling average. Then it would be enough to drop the added values:

```
df.loc[df.index[0] - pd.offsets.Day(1), 'Q'] = df.iloc[-1]['Q']
df.loc[df.index[-2] + pd.offsets.Day(1), 'Q'] = df.iloc[0]['Q']
df = df.sort_index()
df['Q'] = pd.Series(df["Q"].rolling(3, center=True).mean())
```

It gives as expected:

```
                   Q
Date                
1989-01-01  4.000000
1989-01-02  1.666667
1989-01-03  3.666667
1989-01-04  6.000000
1989-01-05  8.000000
1989-01-06  9.666667
1989-01-07  7.000000
```